# Why won't one part of my javascript function run even though it is syntactically correct?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm a programming newbie trying to make a function that asks for a password, but will display an error message if the password attempt is wrong more than five times. I have tried fiddling around with those code a bunch of different ways and it just won't work. I have a variable called count that starts as 0, and each time a wrong password is entered, 1 is supposed to be added to count, and once count is greater than 5, the error message is supposed to be displayed.

```
document.getElementById("word-checker").onclick = function () {
    var count = 0;
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("text-input").value;
    var secretWord = "password123";

    if (count > 5) {
        alert("You have had 5 unsuccessful login attempts. You account has been temporarily locked.");
    } else if (inputValue == secretWord) {
        alert("Your answer is correct!");
        document.getElementById("text-input").value = "";
    } else if (inputValue!==secretWord) {
        count++;
        alert("Your answer is incorrect. Please try again.");
        document.getElementById("text-input").value = "";
    }
}
```

This is driving me insane. I'm sure it's a simple beginner's mistake though. Any input that would help me understand why this won't work would be met with a lot of gratitude.

Comment: Place your `count` variable declaration outside the handler. You are reinitializing it to zero each time a new attempt is made.

Comment: Wow, thanks. As soon as I read that I realized what a dumb-dumb I am. Much appreciated!

Comment: You bet. Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

You are resetting `count` to `0` every time the click event is triggered:

```
document.getElementById("word-checker").onclick = function () {
    var count = 0; // <-- button clicked, set the value to zero.
    // ...
}
```

This means that `count` will never get to `5` (in fact, it never gets to be `> 1` either, as when `count++` increments the value to `1`, it is set back to `0` on the next click). Consequently, the `if (count > 5)` part of the if statement will never be triggered.

You need to declare `count` *outside* of the click event:

```
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("word-checker").onclick = function () {
    // use count here
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are redefining count as 0 every time on the click event. You need to define count as a global outside the function and then ++ on every error.
Also, try to correct your indentation as it helps reading.